# Brown Spots and Yellow Leaves on Hibiscus

Tags: diseases, hibiscus

I get brown spots that eventually turn my Hibiscus leaves yellow and they fall off. It doesn't kill the plant but I have to trim it down when this happens. What is this and what do I do about it? I have supplied an image of the problem.[image]
Thanksenter image description here

[image]i.stack.imgur.com/2Khtw.jpg

Comment: Looks like Black Spot, a fungus disease in the soil. There are chemical and organic sprays on the market, often sold for roses.

Comment: I agree with @YosefBaskin it's anthracnose infection. Apply contact fungicides preferably Copper Oxychloride or if you are new to fungicide dosages opt for Carbendazim+ Mancozeb (Contact+ Systemic) fungicide.  Exercise caution with Copper Oxychloride a slight larger than recommended dose can potentially kill your plant. C+M is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.